# Invert Only White Colors To Black With JQuery On a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible, if yes how, to invert only white colors on an html page to black using jquery? Not looking for inverting all colors, that works. Like this:

```
var css = 'html {-webkit-filter: invert(100%);' +
'-moz-filter: invert(100%);' + 
'-o-filter: invert(100%);' + 
'-ms-filter: invert(100%); }'
```

But I'm looking to invert only white pixels to black pixels of the whole page including images.

Comment: Do you mean any color defined as white or any white pixel (including in images?) The former is easy, the later is nigh-on impossible.

Comment: Preferably the second one, but the first one would be great if that's the only thing possible.

Comment: the second one is not possible..i think that would make the content of the webpage obscure..but why do want to change all the white to black..?if you want inverting colors on any web page to make your eyes less painfull you can use the stylish scripts on userstyles.org or a plugin for chrome like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph?hl=en

Comment: It's for an experimental project. Would really be great to do it with jQuery since that will help me scale it to majority of websites. Just converting white defined colors to black would be a great start. I'll deal with images in a different way in that case.

Comment: For images, you would need to create a separate image for each one, with the white inverted to black. Then on click, change the image to be the one with inverted colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting question, IMHO :)

I wouldn't entrust to `css("color")` because the element can inherit its color from parents. The most reliable method is `getComputedStyle` which returns an actual CSS property of element, doesn't matter how browser calculates it.

Pay attention that color can be in one of the tree forms: a color name like 'white', a short value like '#FFFFFF' or '#ffffff' or rgb / rgba like rgb(255, 255, 255). You should take care on all the cases!

So, the code should be like the following one:

```
$(body').find('*').each(function(){
    var color = window.getComputedStyle($(this).get(0), null).backgroundColor;
    if ((color.toLowerCase() == "white") ||
        (color.toLowerCase() == "#ffffff") ||
        (color.toLowerCase() == "rgb(255,255,255)")) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    }    
});
```

For images you can use canvas. Inside the same loop of elements:

```
if ($(this).attr("tagName") == "img"){
    invertImage($(this).get(0));
}

function invertImage(img){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);    

    var data = imageData.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        if ((data[i] == 255) && (data[i+1] == 255) && (data[i+2] == 255)){
            data[i] = 0;
            data[i+1] = 0;
            data[i+2] = 0;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    $(img).get(0).src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

And finally, if you want to handle also 'almost white' colors, for example '254, 252, 255' than you need to calculate the luma component as

```
Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
```

and threshold the result for something like `>= 250`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "calculate the luma component as"?

Comment: "luma" is Y-component in YUV color encoding system. You can learn more about it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this 
 writing this in on click event

```
$("#your_ID").click(function () {
    $("div").each(function () {
    var color = $(this).css("color");
            if (color == "#FFFFFF") {
                $(this).css("color", "#000000");
            }
 });
});
```

Write your IF case like this to check all "near" white color

```
if(field.css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {

 }
```

change the RGB value to find near white. reference [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm)

Click here for [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uhTr4/44/)

Comment: Tnx for posting this, unfortunately i can't seem to get it to work. Does it only function in certain browsers?

Comment: and white will not be visible in white background. so check once again and and if it works accept this answer otherwise dont.